# Is there an alternative to fastboot erase modemst1/2?

Tags: android, linux, fastboot

I have both a Windows and a Linux (Mint) computer and I need to fix gps on my LG G2 D802 (with a custom CM mod), but I can't do it. I read online that I should erase *modemst1* and *modemst2* partitions but I get an annoying "waiting for device" message every time I try to run fastboot. I read troubleshootings and solutions online but they didn't help me.

- On my Windows I have everything set up and installed (adb and fastboot), adb works but when I put my phone in bootloader mode, fastboot doesn't work.
- On my Linux, I have everything set up, like on Windows. Adb works, but fastboot doesn't, like on Windows. I have a *51-android.rules* with all Android phone *vendorid*s, included mine, but nothing. And yeah I run `sudo` before commands.

Obviously my phone is unlocked (CyanogenMod) and I enabled usb debugging.

Is there an alternative to erase those partitions or a solution to these issues?

Answer (score 0):

i found an alternative here: https://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/108806-gps-not-fixing-with-latest-cm121/

it says:

> I had this problem as well.
>
> Today i used my GPS Status app to reset and re-download my A-GPS data
>   (under "Manage A-GPS state") and changed my gps.conf (/system/etc) to
>   one i found on the net, rebooted, and it seems to have helped. I
>   wasn't able to get a fix indoors at all previously. Now it varies
>   between 10 and 60s. Time will tell if this holds up.
>
> The gps.conf is:
>
> XTRA_SERVER_1=http://xtra1.gpsonextra.net/xtra2.bin
>
> XTRA_SERVER_2=http://xtra2.gpsonextra.net/xtra2.bin
>
> XTRA_SERVER_3=http://xtra3.gpsonextra.net/xtra2.bin
>
> ERR_ESTIMATE=0
>
> NTP_SERVER=north-america.pool.ntp.org
>
> DEBUG_LEVEL = 3
>
> INTERMEDIATE_POS=0
>
> SUPL_VER=0x20000
>
> SUPL_ES=1
>
> CAPABILITIES=0x37
>
> SUPL_HOST=supl.google.com
>
> SUPL_PORT=7275
>
> LPP_PROFILE = 3
>
> NMEA_PROVIDER=0
>
> SGLTE_TARGET=1
>
> A_GLONASS_POS_PROTOCOL_SELECT = 0